# Size of Postgres database growing

Tags: postgresql

Our Postgres database is currently at about 68G of size and growing at a rate of 6G/month. I am investigating ways how to scale the database.

Would be nice if someone can give some advices as I am new about this?

One suggestion I got is to use Amazon RDS. But it has some limitations as we replicate some particular tables between the database instances using Londiste.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Postgres-XL

Answer (score 1):

6 GB a month is only 72 GB a year. so to get to 1 TB of data it is around 15 years. clearl, the amount of data should not be your concern unless you are really doing something fancy.

what kind of queries do you run to require such a small database?